# Decreasing hunger variable overtime using java

Tags: java, game-development

im an experienced python coder who's getting for the first time into java, i'm trying to code a text-based adventure game. I want the game to have a *hunger variable set to 100 that decreases by 5 every 15 seconds.* I tried doing a while loop but it didn't go well. I've done a lot of search online but I didn't found any answer.
This is what i tried

```java
package game;
public class game {
    int hunger = 100;
    int hungerDecreaser = 5;
    while (true) {
        Thread.Sleep(15000);
        hunger - hungerDecreaser;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to catch the InterruptedException that `Thread.sleep()` will throw. `hunger - hungerDecreaser` should also be changed to `hunger -= hungerDecreaser`.

Below is an example of how you can have concurrency.

Main.java file:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create hunger handler
        Runnable hunger = new Hunger();
        //create hunger thread
        Thread thread = new Thread(hunger);
        //start thread
        thread.start();

        //rest of game
        System.out.println("This code will run at the same time as the hunger thread.");
    }
}
```

Hunger.java file:

```
public class Hunger implements Runnable{
    int hunger;
    int hungerDecreaser;

    Hunger() {
        hunger = 100;
        hungerDecreaser = 5;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(15000); // throws InterruptedException
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { // Exception must be caught or else code will not compile
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            hunger -= hungerDecreaser;
            System.out.println("The hunger has decreased to: " + hunger);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot, but now i have just the hunger going down and i can't play the game. Is there a way to get both the hunger decreaser and the game playing at the same time?

Comment: That's because the Thread.sleep() pauses the _entire_ thread (basically all your code). Look into multi-threaded programming to have multiple threads run at the same time.  Here's a general overview: [What is a multi-threaded appplication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313062/what-is-a-multithreaded-application) . Check out [Introduction to Java Threads](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077138/introduction-to-java-threads.html) for a Java specific overview. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, saw both the links that you've recommended to me but I still can't figure out some things... Do I have to create two threads and put the "hungerdecreaser" in one of them and the rest of the code in the other? If so, how should I do that? Let's say that the rest of the code is System.out.println("hello world");, do I have to put it in the public static void run() or into "extends Thread"?

Comment: @Lalle I've updated the answer with a code example of how you could accomplish the concurrency.

Comment: Thank you very much